# Pick up elements of a numpy array for defined intervals

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have two 1-D arrays of array objects (DATA and DEGREE) of the same size. Both arrays are collection of 8 other arrays :

```
DATA = array([array([ 22.]),
   array([ 26.,  16.,  23.,   0.,  20.,  23.,   0.,  19.]),
   array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  20.,   0.,   0.,  18.,  18.,   0.,   0.,
     0.,  23.,  20.,  20.,  15.]),
   array([ 20.,   0.,   0.,  18.,   0.,  13.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
     0.,  25.,  18.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]),
   array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]),
   array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.]),
   array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
   array([ 1.,  0.])], dtype=object)



DEGREE = array([array([0]), 
   array([   0,   45,   90,  135,  180,  -90, -135,  -45]),
   array([-153,  -90, -116, -135,   26,  116,   90,  -63,   63,  180,  153,
    135,    0,  -26,   45,  -45]),
   array([ -18,  123,   56,    0,  161,   18,  180,   90,  -56, -161,   71,
    146,  -33,   33, -123, -146,  108, -108,  -71,  -90]),
   array([  14, -104, -116,  -90,   75,  135,  -75,  -63,   45,   63,  -14,
     26, -135,  -45,    0,   90,  -26,  116,  104]),
   array([  30,   53,   45,  126,   36, -126,   21,  -53,   11,  -45,    0,
    -36,  -11,  -30,  -21]),
   array([-38, -26,  26, -18,  -9,  38,   0,   9,  18]),
   array([-33,  33])], dtype=object)
```

I would like to pick up the elements of DATA array corresponding to those of the DEGREE array defining a certain "alpha" angle interval. For example, for -90<=alpha<-70 I should get the Output array reported below. When no angles are found for a certain angle interval the algorithms should return zero, for example in the case of the first array of the Output.

```
Output = array([array([0]),
        array([23]),
        array([0]),
        array([0]),
        array([1,0]),
        array([0]),
        array([0]),
        array([0])], dtype=object)
```

The idea would be to have alpha varying between -90 and +90 with steps of 20 degrees, i.e. -90<=alpha<-70, -70<=alpha<-50, -50<=alpha<-30 and so on to have finally 9 Output arrays. How could I do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: just to remind that DATA and DEGREE are 1-D arrays of array objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use list comprehensions and masks. The following should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

def val_check(val_in):
    ''' Check for non-zero values in numpy array '''
    if val_in.any():
        return val_in
    else:
        return np.array([0])

# Set tuples of desired ranges
angles = []
angle = -90
while angle < 90:
    angles.append((angle, angle + 20))
    angle = angle + 20

out = []
for ang in angles:
    # List comprehensions to get masks for elements in desired range per array
    mask = [(arr >= ang[0]) * (arr < ang[1]) for arr in DEGREE]
    mask_index = [np.where(m) for m in mask]
    # Include data corresponding to masks
    out_temp = [dat[mi[0]] for (dat, mi) in zip(DATA, mask_index)]
    # Replace empty elements with np.array([0])
    out_temp = np.array([val_check(ot) for ot in out_temp])
    out.append(out_temp)
```

If you want the output as an array instead of a list, include one final line `out = np.array(out)`

Comment: Good! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: p.s. this question is actually linked to my next one: "make a matrix out of 1-D arrays of array objects" maybe you know how to solve that too..